# Visual Studio: Prevent CodeAnalysis from running on cs files included via nuget

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, code-analysis, csproj, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm referencing the [BlingFireNuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlingFireNuget/) package in my csproj. It adds a bunch of files to my project, including a couple cs files, like `BlingFireUtils.cs`. These are adding hundreds of code analysis warnings when I build:

[image]

There must be some way to exclude these from code analysis, but still include them in compilation, but I can't figure out how. I did modify the csproj to at least not include them in Solution Explorer, but that didn't do the trick:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="@(Compile)">
      <Visible Condition="'%(NuGetItemType)' == 'Compile'">false</Visible>
    </Compile>
</ItemGroup>
```

Edit:

I did try modifying the `.editorconfig` to treat these files as generated, even tried the absolute path, and that didn't work either:

```
[C:\Users\unionp\.nuget\packages\blingfirenuget\0.1.8\contentFiles\cs\any\BlingFireUtils.cs]
generated_code = true

[C:/Users/unionp/.nuget/packages/blingfirenuget/0.1.8/contentFiles/cs/any/BlingFireUtils.cs]
generated_code = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Create or modify your `.editorconfig` file and list the files as `generated_code`. See "[Configure Generated code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#configure-generated-code)".

Example:

```
[BlingFireUtils.cs]
generated_code = true
```

Multiple files can be listed in one `.editorconfig` section header as:

```
[file0.cs,file1.cs]
generated_code = true
```

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work for me, even after closing/reopening VS. Is it possible the editorconfig isn't applying to these files since they're not under the file hierarchy rooted in the .editorconfig, but actually in my global nuget directory?

Comment: Yes, it's looking in the directory hierarchy. In the `.editorconfig` you will need to add the path. But I'm not sure if environment variables (i.e. for the user home directory) are recognized and expanded. You will need to test that.

Comment: Unfortunately absolute paths didn't work for me either (see my edit), even after restarting VS

Comment: It would be nice if the injected files came marked with the `[GeneratedCode]` attribute.